# Remove event listeners from movieclip from main timeline

Tags: actionscript

So, i am adding movieclip objects on to the main timeline programatically. 
With-in those movieclips im using a timer event so they will move once added to the stage.

so when my game ends, i want to remove the movieclip objects from the stage, i can do this, but its causing errors because the listeners of the objects are still there.

i cant access the code in the movieclip object timeline from the main timeline to remove the listeners and i dont know how to remove the listener from with-in the movieclip timeline when they are removed!

I hope this makes sense!

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Your MovieClips can listen to Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE to programmatically remove all the event listeners you added earlier. Here is some sample code to show how it is done.

```
    // add this code to an ActionScript class that extends Sprite
    // call initClips() in the constructor

    private var _clipA:MovieClip;
    private var _clipB:MovieClip;
    private var _clipACount:int;
    private var _clipBCount:int;

    private function initClips():void
    {
        // create 2 movieclips and add some common event listeners
        _clipA = new MovieClip();
        _clipA.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onClipAddedToStage);
        _clipA.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onClipRemovedFromStage);
        _clipA.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrameClipA);


        _clipB = new MovieClip();
        _clipB.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onClipAddedToStage);
        _clipB.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onClipRemovedFromStage);
        _clipB.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrameClipB);

        _clipACount = 0;
        _clipBCount = 0;

        addChild(_clipA);
        addChild(_clipB);
    }



    private function onClipAddedToStage(event:Event):void
    {
        var clip:MovieClip = event.currentTarget as MovieClip;
        if(clip == _clipA)
        {
            // position movieclip to dummy values
            clip.x = 40;
            clip.y = 40;
        }
        else if(clip == _clipB)
        {
            clip.x = 200;
            clip.y = 100;
        }
    }

    private function onClipRemovedFromStage(event:Event):void
    {
        var clip:MovieClip = event.currentTarget as MovieClip;
        // good habit to null check in case "as" casting fails
        if(clip != null)
        {
            // remove event listeners for this movieclip instance
            clip.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onClipAddedToStage);
            clip.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onClipRemovedFromStage);

            // there is no penalty for trying to remove event listeners that were not added to this object instance
            clip.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrameClipA); 
            clip.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrameClipB);
        }
    }


    private function onEnterFrameClipA(event:Event):void
    {
        _clipACount++;
        trace("onEnterFrame for clipA " + _clipACount);

        if(_clipACount > 10)
        {
            // for demonstration purposes
            // remove self after a few frames pass
            removeChild(_clipA);
        }

    }   

    private function onEnterFrameClipB(event:Event):void
    {
        _clipBCount++;
        trace("onEnterFrame for clipB " + _clipBCount);

        if(_clipBCount > 20)
        {
            removeChild(_clipB);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are events to receive notification, when a DisplayObject is removed from stage. Just set up listeners for Event.ADDED, Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Event.REMOVED and Event.REMOVE_FROM_STAGE to implement a live cycle for the MovieClips. Start stuff when the MovieClips are added. Remove listeners, stop timers etc, when the MovieClips are removed.